# Adding font sizes to TinyMCE Advanced

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, font-size

I am using Wordpress 4.9.8 and TinyMCE Advanced 4.8.0

I don't seem to find the answer to this anywhere so appologies in advance if I have missed something...

I want to add extra font sizes to the dropdown menu in the editor. I managed to do so by selecting the 'Font sizes' option in the plugins settings and by adding the options to the sizes I need to the 
'**/wp-content/plugins/tinymce-advanced/tinymce-advanced.php**' file as follows:

```
private $fontsize_formats = '8px 10px 12px 13px 14px 16px 20px 24px 28px 32px 36px';
```

This works great but has changed the default font size to 16px (it should be 12px)

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my answer previously on [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/295988/7355). I will port it over here for transparency.

---

This is kind of a 2-parter. The first half will show you how to change the style inside TinyMCE when editing. The second half will show you how to remove things from the toolbar.

## Style TinyMCE

WordPress give us a neat little function called [`add_editor_style()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/295988/7355) which accepts an array of stylesheets, either by URL or relative paths. WordPress default themes usually take advantage of this function and can be seen in the latest [TwentySeventeen theme](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/master/functions.php#L97). First let's create a stylesheet. The name doesn't matter but the location does.

```
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

For simplicity we'll call this `editor-style.css` and save it in the theme:

```
/assets/css/editor-style.css
```

Next we need to tell WordPress to use our stylesheet so we'll open the themes `functions.php` file and add in:

```
/**
 * Theme setup functionality
 *
 * @return void
 */
function prefix_theme_setup() {

    // Relative path to the TinyMCE Stylesheet
    add_editor_style( array( 'assets/css/editor-style.css' ) );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'iqt_theme_setup' );
```

Some plugins could interfere with this such as page builders if they implement their own TinyMCE.

---

## Modify Toolbar

Next, we can use the [`tiny_mce_before_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/tiny_mce_before_init/) [filter hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init) to modify the TinyMCE. In this case, all we need to do if override the font sizes. You can add the following function into your `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * Add Formats to TinyMCE
 * - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/tiny_mce_before_init/
 * - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init
 *
 * @param array $args   - Arguments used to initialize the tinyMCE
 *
 * @return array $args  - Modified arguments
 */
function prefix_tinymce_toolbar( $args ) {

    $args['fontsize_formats'] = "8px 10px 12px 13px 14px 16px 20px 24px 28px 32px 36px";

    return $args;

}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'prefix_tinymce_toolbar' );
```

The `$args` array has an index that accepts a list of font sizes separated by spaces. You can change these to whatever you want, `px`, `em`, `rem` it doesn't matter, just that the list is separated by a space and is a valid `font-size` value.